# How to convert date Column from "Month Year " (Ex. March 2018) to ISO format in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, date

So I have a date column in SQLite table that has the following format for values "January 2018", "February 2018", "March 2018" etc. I want to Order By the date but since this is essentially just a TEXT column, I am not able to. What's the easiest way to convert this date format to an ISO formatted date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
substr(date_column, instr(date_column, ' ') + 1)
|| '-'
|| (CASE substr(date_column, 1, instr(date_column, ' ') - 1)
    WHEN 'January' THEN '01'
    WHEN 'February' THEN '02'
    -- etc
    WHEN 'December' THEN '12'
    END)
|| '-01'
```

will produce a string like `'2018-01-01'` from `'January 2018'`.